# Hardhat testing msg.sender.call

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I use hardhat to test this function:

```
// Pool.sol

function withdraw(uint256 _withdrawAmount) public payable returns (bool) {
    require(_withdrawAmount <= getBalance(), "overdrawn");
    balances[msg.sender] -= _withdrawAmount;
    totalContractBalance -= _withdrawAmount;

    (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: _withdrawAmount}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to withdraw");

    return true;
}
```

by using:

```
// test/Pool.js

it('Should withdrawSomeBalance', async function () {
  await pool.connect(addr1).addBalance(5)
  await pool.connect(addr1).withdraw(2)
  expect(await pool.connect(addr1).getBalance()).to.equal(3)
})
```

I got:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Failed to withdraw'
```

But when I comment out `require(sent, "Failed to withdraw")` in `Pool.sol` it pass the test.

Both `addBalance()` and `getBalance()` pass test.
Is there anything I made incorrectly for the contract or the test?
How can I include the `require(sent, "Failed to withdraw")` and make the whole test more sense? Thanks.

===

Pool.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Pool {
    uint256 totalContractBalance = 0;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances; // user ETH in wei
function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalContractBalance;
}

function addBalance(uint256 _amount) public payable returns (bool) {
    balances[msg.sender] = _amount;
    totalContractBalance += _amount;
    return true;
}

function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[msg.sender];
}

function withdraw(uint256 _withdrawAmount) public payable returns (bool) {
    require(_withdrawAmount <= getBalance(), "overdrawn");
    balances[msg.sender] -= _withdrawAmount;
    totalContractBalance -= _withdrawAmount;

    (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: _withdrawAmount}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to withdraw"); // comment out this will pass the test!

    return true;
}

receive() external payable {}
}
```

/test/Pool.js

```
const { expect } = require('chai')
const { ethers } = require('hardhat')

describe('Pool', function () {
  let Pool, pool, owner, addr1, addr2

  beforeEach(async () => {
    Pool = await ethers.getContractFactory('Pool')
    pool = await Pool.deploy()
    ;[owner, addr1, addr2, _] = await ethers.getSigners()
    //await pool.deployed();
  })

  describe('Deployment', function () {
    it('Should set the right inital balance', async function () {
      expect(await pool.getContractBalance()).to.equal(0)
    })
  })

  describe('Transactions', function () {
    it('Should return contract balance from addBalance', async function () {
      await pool.addBalance(1)
      //await addSomeBalance.wait()
      expect(await pool.getContractBalance()).to.equal(1)
    })
it('Should return user balance from addBalance', async function () {
  await pool.addBalance(11)
  //await addSomeBalance.wait()
  expect(await pool.getBalance()).to.equal(11)
})

it('Should withdrawSomeBalance', async function () {
  await pool.connect(addr1).addBalance(5)
  //await addSomeBalance.wait()
  await pool.connect(addr1).withdraw(2)
  //await withdrawSomeBalance.wait()
  expect(await pool.connect(addr1).getBalance()).to.equal(3)
})
  })
})
```

testing output:

```
  Pool
Deployment
  ✓ Should set the right inital balance
Transactions
  ✓ Should return contract balance from addBalance
  ✓ Should return user balance from addBalance
  1) Should withdrawSomeBalance


  3 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1) Pool
       Transactions
         Should withdrawSomeBalance:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Failed to withdraw'
```

Comment: Hi Graphite! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! You aren't sending ether with `addBalance(5)`, to do so you have to write something like `addBalance(5, {value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("5", "wei")})`.

Comment: Hi @Ismael thanks for replying. In order to have inputs from frontend, I reserve an argument (perhaps there are better ways to do this) in addBalance function:
`function addBalance(uint256 _amount) public payable returns (bool) {
balances[msg.sender] = _amount;
totalContractBalance += _amount;
        return true;
    }`

Comment: You aren't sending ether so there's no way you can withdraw ether from the contract. The value returned by `getBalance()` is just a number it doesn't reflect any ether amount. The function `withdraw` fails because the transfer fails `msg.sender.call{value: _withdrawAmount}("")`.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you so much. Yes, your comments solve my issue and save me a lot of time. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `withdraw` fails because this call returns false indicating the transfer failed

```
msg.sender.call{value: _withdrawAmount}("");
```

It fails because the contract doesn't have enough ether.

The script isn't sending ether with `addBalance(5)` it just increases the internal balances mapping.

To send ether with the call have to write something like this:

```
addBalance(5, {value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("5", "wei")}).
```